# oAuth2 credentials being stored as unicode

Tags: python, django, oauth, double-click

I'm working on storing oauth2 credentials so that I can create services later on.

currently my model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from oauth2client.contrib.django_util.models import CredentialsField
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules

class oAuth(models.Model):
    siteid = models.CharField(max_length=100L, primary_key=True)
    credential = CredentialsField()

    add_introspection_rules([],["^oauth2client\.contrib\.django_util\.models\.CredentialsField"])
```

when I try to save my credentials:

```
credential = flow.step2_exchange(code)
storage = DjangoORMStorage(oAuth, 'siteid', site_id, 'credential')
storage.put(credential)
```

in my DB I have a unicode string being stored which then can't be converted into a oauth object using:

```
storage = DjangoORMStorage(oAuth, 'siteid', site_id, 'credential')
credential = storage.get()
return credential
```

I am getting credentials to be the unicode that was stored previously, I just can't perform the .authorize method on it which is what I need to do,

have I gotten confused somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a while to find (I had been struggling with this for a day or so before asking stack overflow) but..

The returning unicode needs to be made back into an oauth object using I went through the actual calls and found [this](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/contrib/django_util/models.py)

The solution:

```
storage = DjangoORMStorage(oAuth, 'siteid', site_id, 'credential')
credential = storage.get()
credential = CredentialsField().to_python(credentials)
return credential
```

`credential` can now be called as a regular oauth object

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DB is set up to store `utf-8`. Django needs that.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/unicode/#creating-the-database

Comment: My problem is that when I call storage.get() I get the unicode not the original oAuth object so I can't call `.authorize()` on it, I'm not sure if I then need to use the unicode and build an oAuth object, but I can't find any docuentation on that.
I've checked the encoding and it's cp1252 however all of my other tables are the same encoding and everything else seems to work fine

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I now see `DjangoORMStorage` is from the lib itself. I'm out of ideas. :-)

Comment: looking in [client storage](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/client.py) it seems like .get() for the storage actually must return a oauth object which is why I can't understand how it's returning unicode